# is_nothrow_default_constructible with a noexcept(false) default constructor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I was trying to `static_assert` a few type traits to ensure that a custom type had the expected `noexcept` guarantees when I stumbled upon a strange behaviour. The reduced snippet above illustrates the issue:

```
struct DefaultOnly
{
    constexpr DefaultOnly() noexcept(false) {};
};

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<DefaultOnly>);
```

For this simple type GCC 8 passes the `static_assert` while Clang 7 fails it. I don't know which compiler is right. Is this a bug in one of the compilers or is the standard definition of *nothrow default constructible* flexible enough so that both compilers produce valid but different results based on their interpretation of the standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is not directly related to a constructor with `noexcept` specification, but how compilers do treat *constant expressions* when `noexcept` is in play.

If you declare the constructor as no `constexpr`, then both compilers works as expected:

```
struct DefaultOnly
{
    DefaultOnly() noexcept(false) {};
};
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<DefaultOnly>);
```

Back to C++11, *constant expressions* weren't sensible to `noexcept` specification but that went through changes up to C++17. up to now `constexpr` functions are affected by `noexcept` specification.

Clang works as expected.

The following code will show the same behavior as yours:

```
constexpr int foo() noexcept(false) { return 0;}
static_assert(noexcept(foo()));
```

As reference, this is an extract of the [GCC-87603](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87603) report:

> CWG 1129 (which ended up in C++11) added a special case to noexcept for constant expressions, so that:
>
> `constexpr void f() {} static_assert(noexcept(f()));`
>
> CWG 1351 (which ended up in C++14) changed the wording significantly, but the special case remained, in a different form.
>
> P0003R5 (which ended up in C++17) changed the wording again, but the special case was removed (by accident), so now:
>
> `constexpr void f() {} static_assert(!noexcept(f()));`
>
> According to Richard Smith in LLVM 15481, CWG discussed this but decided to keep the behavior as-is. Currently, clang does the right thing for C++17 (and fails for C++14 and C++11, on purpose). g++, however, implemented the special case for C++11 already, but not the change for C++17. Currently, icc and msvc seem to behave like g++.

Also see [GCC-86044](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86044) and the [GCC-88453](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88453) is more specifically equivalent to your case.

Comment: So GCC folks aren't sure whether to get rid of the special case or not because it was removed accidentally. Interesting. Too bad we can't rely on it now ^^'

Answer (score 3):

As of C++17, Clang is right.  Until then, `constexpr` overrode the `noexcept(false)` because the `noexcept` *operator* always [returned true for constant expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept).

Answer (score 1):

`std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<T>` is equivalent to `std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value`, which is specified in [[meta.unary.prop]](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#tab:type-traits.properties) as

> `is_­constructible_­v<T, Args...>` is `true` and the variable definition for `is_constructible`, as defined below, is known not to throw any exceptions ([expr.unary.noexcept]).

The variable definition in question is given in [[meta.unary.prop]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#unary.prop-8)

> The predicate condition for a template specialization `is_­constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented variable `t`:
>
> ```
> T t(declval<Args>()...);
> ```

So, according to the standard, `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v` should be `true` if the above *declaration-statement* "is known to not throw an exception" in the sense of the `noexcept` operator. From [[expr.unary.noexcept/3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.noexcept#3)

> The result of the `noexcept` operator is `true` unless the *expression* is potentially-throwing.

According to [[except.spec]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#def:potentially-throwing,expression):

> An *expression* `e` is potentially-throwing if
>
> […]
>
> - `e` implicitly invokes a function (such as an overloaded operator, an allocation function in a *new-expression*, a constructor for a function argument, or a destructor if e is a full-expression) that is potentially-throwing, or
>
>   […]

Now, the wording in the standard is IMHO a bit imprecise here. The value of `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v` is specified in terms of whether a declaration statement "is known to not throw an exception" and we are referred to the specification of the `noexcept` operator to see what that's supposed to mean. However, the `noexcept` operator is only concerned with expressions while what we are given to work with is a *declaration-statement*. So we're kinda left to guess what the equivalent to the specification of a potentially-throwing *expression* would look like for a *declaration-statement*. My interpretation would be that the intent of the standard is to require `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v` to be `false` in your case because the *declaration-statement* given in the specification would implicitly invoke a constructor with a *potentially-throwing exception specification*…